# play audio in a given time range in ios

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I'm using AVAudioPlayer to play a mp3 file. instead of playing whole mp3, I want to specify play time range, like from 2 seconds to 5 seconds. how to specify the play time range?

Comment: Why do you vote it negative?

Answer (score 0):

You can either add an observer to playback and stop it when currentTime will become the time you want or you can cut your mp3 file to specified time and play it. There are various ways for doing this thing.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do it using AVPlayer, AVPlayerItem and AVAsset. The AVPlayerItem is able to seek in an audio file.

I haven't tested it, but it might look something like this.

```
AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:URL_TO_YOUR_MP3];

AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];

/* start playback at 2 seconds */
[playerItem seekToTime:CMTimeMake(2.0, 1.0) completionHandler:^(BOOL finished) {

    /* Instantiate player */
    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

    /* Start playback */
    [player play];

    /* Pause player in 3 seconds */
    [player performSelector:@selector(pause) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];

}];
```